# Multithreading + RxJava observe on condition

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, rx-java

I have a long running task which as a result generates regular files and a main file that lists others.

Scheduler regenerates this files once in a day through cron.

The task flow is implemented using `rx-java`.

The problem is if one request comes in and starts the task or the task gets ran by a scheduler and then while task is in progress some other request comes and don't wait for task to complete, instead firing another execution.

So the question is how to sync on task execution, so it will be done only once ?

This is sample code:

```
@Service
public class FileService {
    @Autowired FileRepository fileRepository;
    @Autowired List<Pipeline> pipelines;

    public Observable<File> getMainFile() {
        if (fileRepository.isMainFileExists())
            return Observable.just(fileRepository.getMainFile());
        else
            return generate(() -> fileRepository.getMainFile());
    }

    public Observable<File> getFile(String fileName) {
        if (fileRepository.isMainFileExists())
            return Observable.just(fileRepository.getFile(fileName));
        else
            return generate(() -> fileRepository.getFile(fileName));
    }

    Observable<File> generate(Func0<File> whenGenerated) {
        return Observable.from(pipelines)
                // other business logic goes here
                // after task execution finished just get needed file
                .map(isAllPipelinesSuccessful -> {
                    return whenGenerated.call();
                });
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 4 * * ?")
    void scheduleGeneration() {
        generate(() -> fileRepository.getMainFile()).subscribe();
    }
}
```

And it's called from controller, sample code below:

```
@RestController
public class FileController {
    private static final Long TIMEOUT = 1_000 * 60 * 10L; //ten mins
    @Autowired FileService fileService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/mainfile", produces = "application/xml")
    public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>> getMainFile() {
        DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>(TIMEOUT);
        Observable<File> observableMainFile = fileService.getMainFile();
        observableMainFile
                .map(this::fileToInputStreamResource)
                .map(resource -> ResponseEntity.ok().cacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(1, TimeUnit.HOURS).cachePublic()).body(resource))
                .subscribe(deferredResult::setResult, ex -> {
                deferredResult.setErrorResult(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(null));
                });
        return deferredResult;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/files/{filename:.+}", produces = "application/xml")
    public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>> getFile(@PathVariable("filename") String filename) {
        DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>(TIMEOUT);
        Observable<File> observableFile = fileService.getFile(filename);
        observableFile
                .map(this::fileToInputStreamResource)
                .map(resource -> ResponseEntity.ok().cacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(1, TimeUnit.HOURS).cachePublic()).body(resource))
                .subscribe(deferredResult::setResult, ex -> {
                    boolean isFileNotFound = FileNotFoundException.class.isInstance(ex.getCause());
                    HttpStatus status = isFileNotFound ? HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND : HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
                    deferredResult.setErrorResult(ResponseEntity.status(status).body(null));
                });
        return deferredResult;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have something like the following, but I think there are way better solutions to this. I am using RxJava2-RC5.

1. Answer lacks the checking, that task has been executed.
   https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7b4717cea7ddce270a2e39850a3bd2a4

UPDATE::

```
interface FileRepository {
        String getFile();

        Boolean isMainFileExists();
}

private static Scheduler executorService = Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1));

@org.junit.Test
public void schedulerTest123() throws Exception {
        FileRepository fRepo = mock(FileRepository.class);

        when(fRepo.getFile()).thenReturn("");
        when(fRepo.isMainFileExists()).thenReturn(false);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
            getFile(fRepo, executorService).subscribe();
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
            getFile(fRepo, executorService).subscribe();
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        Thread.sleep(3_000);

        when(fRepo.getFile()).thenReturn("DasFile");
        when(fRepo.isMainFileExists()).thenReturn(true);

        Thread t3 = new Thread(() -> {
            getFile(fRepo, executorService).subscribe();
        });

        t3.start();

        Thread.sleep(5_000);
}

private Observable<String> getFile(FileRepository fileRepo, Scheduler scheduler) {
        return Observable.defer(() -> {
            try {
                if (fileRepo.isMainFileExists()) {
                    return Observable.fromCallable(fileRepo::getFile)
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .doOnNext(s -> printCurrentThread("Get File from Repo"));
                } else {
                    return startLongProcess().doOnNext(s -> printCurrentThread("Push long processValue"));
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                return Observable.error(ex);
            }
        }).subscribeOn(scheduler).doOnSubscribe(disposable -> printCurrentThread("SUB"));
    }

private Observable<String> startLongProcess() {
        return Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
            printCurrentThread("Doing LongProcess");

            Thread.sleep(5_000);

            return "leFile";
        });
}

private void printCurrentThread(String additional) {
        System.out.println(additional + "_" + Thread.currentThread());
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: by this way all calls to generate will be thread confined, but aren't they will be enqueued, so when one completes the other will be called ?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I will edit my answer. I though you would add your check in fromCallable.

Comment: Code is a bit messy, but the idea is to enqueue subscriptions to one thread and defer execution, so when each gets pulled from the queue additional check is made ?

Comment: Also could you explain, I'm using `observeOn` on `pipelines` (I didn't put it in the question) is there will be any interfering if i use such model ?

Comment: If multiple thread subscribe to getFile()-observable, only one will be let in untill the observable finishes. Only one because of "subscribeOn" has a threadpool with only one thread. SubscribeOn will create emissions on given scheduler. So everything down will be on the same thread. flatMap will be called on the same thread. ObserveOn will only move oNext events to another thread through the scheduler. I dont think that my solution is good, because getFile() will block until longProcess finishes.

Comment: Also i think there's a problem with scheduled task when it will be fired during some request is in progress